# What's actually going on when I call bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I learned how to use bibtex from the LaTeX wikibook, found [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management#BibTeX). They say that to compile a LaTeX file that uses bibtex, you need to call pdflatex once, followed by bibtex, followed by two more calls to pdflatex. I'm wondering: what's actually going on at each of these steps? Why do I need to run pdflatex and bibtex in that order?

Comment: In some ways, this is a duplicate of [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/5764). The [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/5764) by Paul describes how it all works...